# React: defaultChecked set to true if object key value is also true

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have this dataset that has the `amenities` which is also an object within an object:

```
{
    name: "California Maki Resort",
    price_per_night: 2804.0,
    description:
      "On a lush 16-hectare island with white-sand beaches, this relaxed resort is 5 km from the jetty in Cadiz Viejo, a village on the mainland.",
    address: "Cadiz Viejo",
    city: "Cadiz",
    amenities: 
      {
        tv: false,
        reservation: false,
        moderate_noise: true
    },
    image:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591017403286-fd8493524e1e"
  }
```

As you can see I have the `tv`, `reservation`, and `moderate_noise` subfields under amenities. On my edit resort screen, I need to pull up the data from amenities and set them to `defaultChecked` if the value is true. So what I did is I map through the object like this:

```
{ 
            Object.keys(resort.amenities).reduce((result, key) => {
                return (
                    <div className="form-group"> 
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                name="tv"
                defaultChecked={result["tv"] === true}
                id="tv" value={true} ref={register} />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tv">TV</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                name="reservation"
                defaultChecked={result["reservation"] === true}
                id="reservation" value={true} ref={register}/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="reservation">Reservation</label>
            </div>

    )}
}
```

But this gave me some errors that it can't read the `result["tv"]` I am not sure to properly checked each value if they are true or not but I want it to be checked on checkbox if the value of the key (eg. tv) in the database is true. Please help!

Note: `resort.amenities` returns the object above data and is working fine, I just can't run since I think my way of mapping through this object is not right.

UPDATE: Just to give you the complete code picture here it is:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from 'react-notifications-component'
import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css'
import 'animate.css'
import  Message from '../components/Message'
import  Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { listResortDetails, updateResort } from '../actions/resortActions'
import { RESORT_UPDATE_RESET } from '../constants/resortConstants'

const ResortEditAdminScreen = ({ match, history }) => {

    const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm()
    const resortId = match.params.id
    const [image, setImage] = useState('')
    const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const resortDetails = useSelector(state => state.resortDetails)
    const { loading, error, resort } = resortDetails 

    const resortUpdate = useSelector(state => state.resortUpdate)
    const { 
        loading: loadingUpdate, 
        error: errorUpdate, 
        success: successUpdate 
    } = resortUpdate 

     useEffect(() => {

         console.log(resort.amenities)

        if(successUpdate){
            dispatch({ type: RESORT_UPDATE_RESET })
            history.push('/admin/resortsList')
            store.addNotification({
                title: 'Success!',
                message: 'Resort successfully updated.',
                type: 'success',                       
                container: 'top-right',               
                animationIn: ["animate__animated", "animate__fadeInRight"],   
                animationOut: ["animate__animated", "animate__fadeOutRight"],  
                dismiss: {
                  duration: 4000
                }
              })
        } else {

            if(!resort.name || resort._id !== resortId){
                dispatch(listResortDetails(resortId))
            }

              }
        }
     }, [dispatch, history, resortId, resort, successUpdate])

     const uploadFileHandler = async(e) => {
         const file = e.target.files[0]
         const formData = new FormData()
         formData.append('image', file)
         setUploading(true)

         try{
             const config = {
                 headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                 }
             }
          
             const { data } = await axios.post('/api/upload', formData, config)
             setImage(data)
             setUploading(false)
         } catch(error){
            console.error(error)
            setUploading(false)
         }
     }



    const submitHandler = (data, e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { name, pricePerNight, description, address, city, province, zipCode, phone, email, website, image, tv, reservation, moderateNoise, freeWifi, trendy, creditCard, bar, animals, kids } = data

        dispatch(updateResort({ 
            _id: resortId,
            name,
            price_per_night: pricePerNight,
            description,
            address,
            city,
            province,
            zip_code: zipCode,
            phone,
            email,
            website,
            image,
            amenities: {
                tv,
                reservation,
                moderate_noise: moderateNoise,
                free_wifi: freeWifi,
                trendy,
                credit_card: creditCard,
                bar,
                animals,
                kids
            }
        }))
    }



    return ( 
        <>
            <h1>Edit Resort</h1>
    { loadingUpdate && <Loader /> }    
    { errorUpdate && <Message variant='danger'>{errorUpdate}</Message> }   
    { loading ? <Loader /> : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message> : (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}> 
            <div className="form-group"> 
            <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                            defaultValue={resort.name}
                            className={`form-control ${errors.name ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                            id="name"
                            ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 2, maxLength: 30 })}
                        />
                        { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Name is required.</p> }
                        { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Name is too short.</p> }
                        { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Name is exceeds maximum length.</p> }
            </div>
 
            <div className="form-group"> 
                    <label for="name">Price Per Night</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="pricePerNight"
                        defaultValue={resort.price_per_night}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.pricePerNight ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="pricePerNight"
                        ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 2, maxLength: 5, pattern: /^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/ })}
                    />
                    { errors.pricePerNight && errors.pricePerNight.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Price is required.</p> }
                    { errors.pricePerNight && errors.pricePerNight.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Price is too small.</p> }
                    { errors.pricePerNight && errors.pricePerNight.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Price exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                    { errors.pricePerNight && errors.pricePerNight.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">That is not a valid price.</p> }
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea
                    name="description"
                    defaultValue={resort.description}
                    className = {`form-control ${errors.description ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                    id="description"
                    rows="5"
                    ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 100, maxLength: 500})}
                    />
                    {errors.description && errors.description.type === 'required' && <p className="text-danger">Description is required.</p>}
                    { errors.description && errors.description.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Description is too short.</p> }
                    { errors.description && errors.description.type === 'maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Description exceeds maximum length.</p>}
                    
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="address">Address</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="address"
                        defaultValue={resort.address}
                        className= {`form-control ${errors.address ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="address"
                        ref={register({ required: true })}
                    />
                    { errors.address && errors.address.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Address is required.</p> }
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="province">Province</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="province"
                        defaultValue={resort.province}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.province ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="province"
                        ref={register({ required: true })}
                    />
                    { errors.province && errors.province.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Province is required.</p> }
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="zip_code">Zip Code</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="zipCode"
                        defaultValue={resort.zip_code}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.zipCode ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="zipCode"
                        ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 4,  maxLength: 4, pattern: /^[0-9]*$/ })}
                    />
                    { errors.zipCode && errors.zipCode.type === 'required' && <p className="text-danger">Zip Code is required.</p>}
                    {errors.zipCode && errors.zipCode.type === 'minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Zip Code must consist with 4 digits.</p>}
                    { errors.zipCode && errors.zipCode.type === 'maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Zip Code must consist with 4 digits.</p>}
                    { errors.zipCode && errors.zipCode.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">Not a valid Zip Code.</p> }
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="city">City</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="city"
                        defaultValue={resort.city}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.city ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="city"
                        ref={register({ required: true })}
                    />
                    { errors.city && errors.city.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">City is required.</p> }
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="phone"
                            defaultValue={resort.phone}
                            className={`form-control ${errors.phone ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                            id="phone"
                            ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 10, maxLength: 13, pattern: /(^0|[89]\d{2}-\d{3}\-?\d{4}$)|(^0|[89]\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$)|(^63[89]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)|(^63[89]\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$)|(^[+]63[89]\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$)|(^[+]63[89]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)|(^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$)/})}
                    />
                    { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Phone is required.</p> }
                    { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Phone length is too small.</p> }
                    { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Phone exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                    { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">Phone is not a valid phone.</p> }
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        defaultValue={resort.email}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.email ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="email"
                        ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 8, maxLength: 30, pattern: /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/ })}
                    />
                    { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Email is required.</p> }
                    { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Email length is too small.</p> }
                    { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Email exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                    { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">That is not a valid email.</p> }
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="website">Website</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="website"
                        defaultValue={resort.website}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.website ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="website" 
                        ref={register({ required: true, pattern: /^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(ftp|http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\/)[\w#]+)*(\/\w+\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?$/ })}
                    />
                    { errors.website && errors.website.type === 'required' && <p className="text-danger">Website is required.</p>}
                    { errors.website && errors.website.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">Not a valid website url.</p> }
            </div>

            <div className="form-group"> 
               <label for="uploadImage">Upload Image</label>
                <input 
                type="file" 
                className="form-control-file"
                id="uploadImage" 
                onChange={uploadFileHandler}
                ref={register} 
                />
            </div>
            { uploading && <Loader /> }
            
            
            { 
            Object.keys(resort.amenities).reduce((result, key) => {
                return (
                    <div className="form-group"> 
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                name="tv"
                defaultChecked={result["tv"] === true}
                id="tv" value={true} ref={register} />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tv">TV</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                name="reservation"
                defaultChecked={resort.amenities.reservation === true}
                id="reservation" value={true} ref={register}/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="reservation">Reservation</label>
            </div>
        </>
    )}

export default ResortEditAdminScreen
```

UPDATE: Its showing this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tv' of undefined`

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: That's a good suggestion. However, the application is kinda big and it's hard to squeeze and to take piece by piece to put it inside codesandbox. However, the thoughts of the problem is there, I just need to find a way to loop through the object and check the three subfields of amenities if they are set to true

Comment: why did you use `reduce`?

Comment: I thought reduce will do it faster? Is there a better way to map through it?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tv' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `Object.keys` and `reduce` as you can get the values directly from the `amenities` object.

```
return (
  <div className="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        name="tv"
        defaultChecked={resort.amenities.tv === true}
        id="tv"
        value={true}
        ref={register}
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="tv">
        TV
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        name="reservation"
        defaultChecked={resort.amenities.reservation === true}
        id="reservation"
        value={true}
        ref={register}
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="reservation">
        Reservation
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I tried this. But it doesn't read the `resort.amenities.tv` All its showing me that resort.amenities is an object that's why I am trying to loop through it.

Comment: It should based on the information in your question, so please update your question to include additional details so we can help you out.

Comment: What is the value of `resort.amenities` when rendering the inputs?

Comment: the object I posted above

Comment: I'm not really sure how to help as everything should work with the information you have provided in your question.  The only way forward would be to provide a code sandbox that reproduces the error you are seeing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226823/discussion-between-marc-solva-and-mark-skelton).

Comment: It says TypeError: Cannot read property 'tv' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use JS map like this:

```
return Object.keys(resort.amenities).map((name, index) => {
      return (
        <label key={index}>
          <input                
            type="checkbox"
            checked={resort.amenities[name]}                
          />
          {name}
        </label>
      );
});
```

Comment: It's returning TypeError: Cannot read property 'tv' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you use an `Object.keys()`, you are actually creating an array of keys and you do not have access to the values for example:

```
console.log(Object.keys(resort.amenities)) ///[tv,reservation,moderate_noise]
```

And to access the values you have to use the `Object.values()`

```
console.log(Object.values(resort.amenities)) ///[false,false,true]
```

And for your code when use `reduce`

```
Object.keys(resort.amenities).reduce((result, key) => {
 console.log(result) ///tv , undefined
}
```

For this reason, it displays an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tv' of undefined`

I do not understand why you want to convert it to an array when it can be used directly!

I suggest this

```
<div className="form-group"> 
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                name="tv"
                defaultChecked={resort ?resort.amenities.tv === true :false}
                id="tv" value={true} ref={register} />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tv">TV</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                name="reservation"
               defaultChecked={resort ?resort.amenities.reservation === true :false}
                id="reservation" value={true} ref={register}/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="reservation">Reservation</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Same output `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tv' of undefined`

Comment: I think I realized where your problem is .. I updated my answer   @Marc Solva